# Interpreting dummy variable in Heckman 2SLS

Tags: categorical-data, interaction, endogeneity, 2sls, heckman

My question is regarding interpreting the output of a Heckman 2SLS.

**Background information:** I am exploring how institutional investor presence affects investments and firm performance during recessions.  Yet, there is a selection issue because institutions may choose to invest in firms which have certain investment strategies or performances.  And so, I employ the Heckman 2SLS model.

My code in SAS is:

```
proc qlim data = data heckit;
*selection equation;
model dumhi = dumsp500 capx q lnat salesgrowth lev / discrete;   
*equation of interest; 
model capx q liq salesgrowth vol rec / select(dumhi=1);                  
run;
```

In an OLS or fixed effects model, I would estimate the model:

```
capx = dumhi rec rec*dumhi q liq salesgrowth vol
```

where the coefficient on the interaction term (`rec*dumhi`) is the coefficient of interest.

**And now my question:**
In the second stage of Heckman 2SLS where the inverse mills ratio of my institutional investor equation is included in the estimation of investments, I cannot figure out how to include the institutional investor-recessionary interaction term due to a linearity issue.

I did include `rec` already -- is this basically the same thing as the interaction variable? I ask this because when we set up the second equation, we are imposing institutional investors = 1. No?

**So, does `rec` in the Heckman model essentially tell me the same thing as `rec*dumhi` in OLS model since we are imposing `dumhi=1` in the selection criteria? Or am I not clear in my understanding of the model???**